# Hammerhead worm

Tags: species-identification, zoology

[image]

Which Bipalium is this worm? It has no tripe. Nor head collar. It is dark brown as can be seen in the image. This worm is right now in Mauritius. Please help me recognise this Hammerhead worm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but I think that this is a Hammerhead that comes from Asia: the Humbertum Covidum. It is a new, invasive species, hence the name. I am not sure because the Humbertum Covidum tends to be "Fatter", and your Hammerhead is longer. Another reason why I am not sure about this is that the Humbertum Covidum is a Asiatic species, which is very rare in Mauritius. However, I think this is the most accurate response, and I hope this helped!